# Laravel - Select child where param

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a question with laravel relationship OneToMany. My database have 2 table product and product_entry. Product will have infomation to choose same price... and product_entry will have infomation about infomation.

1 Product have have many product_entry will another language. But site only 1 language in the same time, so have anyway i only choose product_entry have product_entry_language same current language?

Ex: i have 1 product a with language "en" and "es". Normal, current language is "en". In blade, i must foreach product->product_entries and if(product_entry_language == "en") { ** get Info **} => I want don't need run foreach

Model

```
class Product extends Model
{
    use TransformableTrait;

    protected $table = 'product';
    protected $fillable = ['product_code','product_id'];

    public function entries()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Entities\ProductEntry', 'product_entry_product_id', 'product_id');
    }

}

class ProductEntry extends Model
{
    use TransformableTrait;
    protected $table = 'product_entry';
    protected $fillable = ['product_entry_product_id','product_entry_name'];

}
```

[image]

Comment: please post your models too.

Comment: I had added Model

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by

```
Product::with(['entries' => function ($q) {
  $q->where('product_entry_language', \App::getLocale());
}])->get();
```

`\App::getLocale()` is the current laravel locale

Answer (score 1):

Use a [constraint](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads), for example:

```
Product::with(['product_entry' => function ($q) use($language) {
    $q->where('language', $language);
}])->get();
```

Where `product_entry` is relationship name.